# Dynamic left and right margins?

Tags: css

I want my website to work well for both desktop and mobile view.  When viewed on desktop, I want it to have a pretty big margins on the left and right side. (Image below) . However, when I shrink to to mobile view. They need to reduce to around 10px.  How can I do this?

Currently I only have a

```
.body {
margin-left: 200px;
margin-right: 200px;
```

But this doesn't work well for mobile view...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rP2UU.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmzev.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media Queries: How to target desktop, tablet, and mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a fixed number as a margin will only work for your current resolution. Try changing the desktop resolution and you will see what I'm talking about.

Instead of using 200px, use `auto`, as that value will fill up the remainder of the space.

```
.body {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

That's one of the ways you can use to center an HTML element.

Comment: are there any constraints we can add on top of it? Say 10px of margin with auto? (currently it's at 0px)

Comment: I would add 10px padding to the `body` element. (Honestly, I always use `rem` as spacing, never pixels, rarely percentage.)